# Geoserver WFS-T, write to PostGIS and default table values (current_user() and now())

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs-t

In my table definition I have default values for auditing i.e logging the database user creating the record and time

```
date_created date NULL DEFAULT now(),
edited_by varchar NULL DEFAULT "current_user"(),
```

When a record is inserted via Geoserver WFS-T these default values are not triggered. I am curious to why and if I can do something about it?

Both these basic examples triggers the default values to inject expected default values

```
INSERT INTO test_table
(notes, dato, edited_by)
VALUES('test', now(), "current_user"());

INSERT INTO test_table
(notes)
VALUES('test2');
```

Make me belive Geoserver actually produces this SQL?

```
INSERT INTO test_table
    (notes, dato, edited_by)
    VALUES('test', null, null);
```

Comment: Turn the logging up to geotools dev and you should see the actual query that's sent

Comment: Thanks, will look into geotools, thats new to me. I tried to check to running queries, but pgadmin3 has removed this option so I need to find out that too =)

Comment: Bumped up logging to geotools dev and could see the queries. As expected GS is setting the "date" and "edited_by" to null so the default is not triggered. Is there a clever way of avoiding that or maybe using trigger functions in postgres is the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using triggers in the database for the operation rather than rely on default table definitions.